# Are there regulations that limit the airports an air carrier can visit based on rescue equipment?

Tags: faa-regulations, commercial-operations, firefighting

ICAO Annex 14 (which deals primarily with SARPS for international airports) outlines requirements for rescue and firefighting that the airports shall have based on the *fuselage lengths* of the planes that visit said airports. Each category would define the equipment, amount of foam, discharge rate, etc.

Here the international airports comply with the users' requirements. It made me think of the other way around.

Suppose a pilot flies a tiny GA plane to a remote uncontrolled airport on a scenic tour. I don't expect that airport to have any means of rescue and firefighting apart from perhaps a call made to the local police.

But now suppose an air carrier decides to carry passengers to that airport.

Are there regulations that limit the airports an air carrier can visit based on rescue equipment? If not, how is the minimum level/category of rescue and firefighting guaranteed when not dealing with international airports?

Comment: I suspect this is covered by FAR Part 121 or the opspecs (or international equivalent). Search term: ARFF

Comment: Runway length of the "remote uncontrolled airport" would also be a factor. Many passenger carrying airplanes need longer runways than the small rural runways offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For at least part 121 operations supported by part 139 certified airports or 139 airports that have [unscheduled passenger traffic in aircraft capable of carrying more than 31](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&SID=8313bccee050ec81d7e8fb3377331177&rgn=div5&view=text&node=14:3.0.1.1.14&idno=14) passengers; [yes](https://www.faa.gov/airports/airport_safety/aircraft_rescue_fire_fighting/)

> Operators of Part 139 airports must provide aircraft rescue and
>   firefighting (ARFF) services during air carrier operations that
>   require a Part 139 certificate. The guidance and resources below
>   address ARFF training, ARFF vehicles, and other aviation fire and
>   rescue requirements.

Comment: Good info but only a partial answer - part 139 regulates the airports but the question is explicitly asking about regs that apply to the airlines.

Comment: @pericynthion these regulations _do_ apply to airlines, all airlines flying scheduled operations here in the us are all under part 121 and will need to land at a 139 airport (or the airports they want to land at need to be 139 depending on how you look at it). You need to bounce through some regulations but the chain is direct. However airlines _may_ have op-specs that are more stringent than what the FAA needs. That is the choice of the airline and not a regulation per say.

Comment: Yeah I guess the missing link is the reg that says "121 airlines must use 139 airports". I tried (briefly) but failed to find it.

Comment: Ah, here it is: https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/14/121.590